# Leveraging an existing Java Android project in a .NET MAUI app

Tags: .net, maui

I have an existing Java Android project building in Android Studio. In the long term I may port the source over to C# in a .NET MAUI app in order to have it run on multiple platforms. But for the moment I'd like to leverage the non-UI parts of the existing Android project in a .NET MAUI Android app I've built in Visual Studio 2022 Preview. Would anyone know of resources which describe my options? For example, copy the Android code into my MAUI project's Platforms/Android folders, or build the Java Android project in Android Studio as components callable on the device from a .NET MAUI app.